# The operation cannot be completed because the pipe was closed. This may have been caused by the application on the other end of the pipe exiting

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, hosting

I have WCF application and I added a client to consume the service. there is another  service written by another developer that sends message to my service.
My service is hosted locally and opened port for access. my service acceps the request from the other  service and logs the message.

But I am getting this error : The operation cannot be completed because the pipe was closed.  This may have been caused by the application on the other end of the pipe exiting.
My service is installed locally and is started.

I tried telenet but it also throws error : Connection to host lost...

Service class

```
    namespace InboundMessage.Service;
    Operator: IOperator {

    }
    namespace InboundMessage.Service;
    IOperator {

    }
```

App.config

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">
        </compilation>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="meta">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator" behaviorConfiguration="meta" >
            <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                           <add baseAddress = "http://X:Port/InboundMessage.Service/"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Client

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>

            <binding name="InboundMessage.Service" />

          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://X:port/InboundMessage.Service/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InboundMessage.Service"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" name="InboundMessage.Service" />


        </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: k, its obvious - but, are u sure the server is running?

Comment: @Dreamer not sure if i understand what you are asking? service or server? the service is in my local machine